# Createing an Enumeration lookup. Multiple keys to an single object

Tags: java, enums, java-stream

I've been using Joshua Bloch's excellent pattern to create look ups from strings (or other types) to enumeration objects. After creating the enumeration objects we need to create a map as:

```
private static final Map<String, MyEnumType> MY_MAP =
    Stream.of(values())
          .collect(toMap(MyEnumType::myFunction, e -> e));
```

where `myFunction` return the string I want to map. We then create a static method that uses the Map to look up objects by key.

This works well, but now I have a requirement to map each enumeration object from *multiple* strings.

I've updated myFunction to return `List<String>`. Now I want my stream to iterate over the list, inserting `e` objects into the Map, but I can't quite work out how.

I think the problem is that if I create a Stream I loose the `e` object to insert.

**Update:** There appears to be a bit of confusion about what I'm asking to do. I've got two working answers (so I'm happy) but I'll add an example which might help anybody who is looking to solve the same problem.

Consider an enumeration of days of the week - the type should have exactly 7 objects in it. I'm trying to write a look up method from a text description. The TUESDAY object needs to be mapped from two different keys - `tuesday` and `tue`. The `myFunction` method will return both of these keys in a List

For look up purposes I need my `Map<String, Week>` to have two keys pointing to the TUESDAY object.

Comment: And what would be the type of the Map, if a List<String> is returned ? or which String to take ? Or like all element of the List have to have the znum as value

Comment: are you sure you din't want that in reserve? `Map<MyEnumType, List<String>>`, potentially it this enum is `Color` and you would have a `Map` like : `["red", "RED"] = Color.RED` and you would want to search against "red" that would not be a map look-up anymore

Comment: btw, why not leave the map as it is and simply map different keys to the same value? like `red == Color.RED` and `RED == Color.RED`?

Comment: @Eugene Your second proposition is what I understood, get the List and map all values as key, and Enum as value

Comment: @azro probably, this is still unclear, we need to see what `MyEnumType::myFunction` does

Comment: @Eugene, I might have missed something, but what is the advantage of changing my map to Map<MyEnumType, List<String>>. How would I look up the enumeration from the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your title states *Multiple keys to a single object* I would suppose that you want to map each object from the List, to the the same enum element, like to have several ways to get it

It'll iterate over the enum, and for each one, it will take the `List<Strings>` and create some `Entry` (a key/value) and them associate them to build the map

*I add a basic enum for the demo, where `myFunction` returns the name of the enum in lower and in upper case*

```
 enum AirplaneBrand{    
    AIRBUS(Arrays.asList("A380","A330")),
    BOEING(Arrays.asList("787","737"));       

    private List<String> values;    
    AirplaneBrand(List<String> values){ this.values = values; }    
    public List<String> myFunction(){  return values; }        
  }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final Map<String, AirplaneBrand> MY_MAP =  
            Stream.of(AirplaneBrand.values())
                  .flatMap(en -> en.myFunction().stream().map(elt -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,AirplaneBrand>(elt, en)))
                  .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

       System.out.println(MY_MAP);                 // {A330=AIRBUS, A380=AIRBUS, 787=BOEING, 737=BOEING}
        System.out.println(MY_MAP.get("737"));     // BOEING
        System.out.println(MY_MAP.get("A380"));    // AIRBUS
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a plus one from me for the simple fact that I flew all of those :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment to take an extra line

```
private static final Map<String, MyEnumType> MY_MAP;

static {
    Map<String, MyEnumType> local = new HashMap<>();
    EnumSet.allOf(MyEnumType.class).forEach(e -> e.getValues().forEach(s -> local.put(s, e)));
    MY_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(local);
}
```

which result for

```
public enum MyEnumType {

    RED(List.of("red", "dark red")),
    BLUE(List.of("blue", "light blue", "dark blue"));

    private List<String> values;

    MyEnumType(List<String> values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public List<String> getValues()
    {
        return values;
    }
}
```

to the mapping

```
red -> RED
blue -> BLUE
light blue -> BLUE
dark red -> RED
dark blue -> BLUE
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I prefer the simplicity of your solution, but I've accepted the other answer on the basis that it will fail if the same key is used by two enumerations. (It's a shame I can't accept both answers) Sorry